# SMTP 450 when sending mail with Net::SMTP

Tags: perl, email, smtp

SO.

I'm failing at sending mail from my Perl script. This is what my code looks like:

```
use Net::SMTP;
$smtp = Net::SMTP->new("smtpserver.mydomain.com");
$smtp->mail("myemail\@mydomain.com");
$smtp->to("myemail\@mydomain.com");
$smtp->data();                               
$smtp->datasend("From: myemail\@mydomain.com\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: myemail\@mydomain.com\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: Test message\n");
$smtp->datasend("Just a test message.\n");
$smtp->dataend();                   
$smtp->quit;
```

This is what the debug option throws:

```
Net::SMTP>>> Net::SMTP(2.31)
Net::SMTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::SMTP>>>     Exporter(5.64_03)
Net::SMTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.32)
Net::SMTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.31)
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 220 ESMTP Postfix
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250-
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250-SIZE
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250-ETRN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250-STARTTLS
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250 DSN
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> MAIL FROM:<myemail@mydomain.com>
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 250 2.1.0 Ok
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> RCPT TO:<myemail@mydomain.com>
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 450 4.7.1 <localhost.localdomain>: Helo command rejected: Service temporarily unavailable
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> DATA
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> From: myemail@mydomain.com
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> To: myemail@mydomain.com
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> Subject: Test message
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> Just a test message.
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> .
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)<<< 221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye.
Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x1d1a06c)>>> QUIT
```

The interesting part is that the SMTP server replies with 250 OK when I talk directly to it and I receive the mail just fine:

```
220 ESMTP Postfix
MAIL FROM:<myemail@mydomain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<myemail@mydomain.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Just a test message.
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B68672C02B
```

Does someone have some light to shed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 450 is usually "The server could not access the mailbox to deliver the message" Did you try another mail address to send to?

Comment: Just did. Same result. The Perl script didn't work, SMTP worked.

Comment: I used it and it is working, something might be wrong in your domain setup.

Comment: oh and also add $smtp->datasend("\n"); underneath $smtp->datasend("Subject: Test message\n"); in a new line, else it will not show mesage text.

Comment: You did it. You gave the hint I needed. It was the domain setup. I had to use the method $smtp->hello("smtpserver.mydomain.com"). I did not do so before because perldoc said: "Since this method is invoked automatically when the Net::SMTP object is constructed the user should normally not have to call it manually." It seems like this is an abnormal case and I'm perfectly OK with that :) Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Post this as an answer and accept it so that the question does not show as unanswered.  Thanks.

Comment: @horlay please see the response by triplee to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting this as an answer instead so that it can be accepted as the answer, as requested by triplee.

Something might be wrong in your domain setup.

also add $smtp->datasend("\n"); underneath $smtp->datasend("Subject: Test message\n"); in a new line, else it will not show mesage text.

like this.

```
    $smtp->datasend("Subject: Test message\n");
    $smtp->datasend("\n");
    $smtp->datasend("Just a test message.\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP server (postfix) "does not like" hostname used in `EHLO` command but rejects it  in reply to `RCPT TO:` command.

```
>>> MAIL FROM:<myemail@mydomain.com>
<<< 250 2.1.0 Ok
....
>>> RCPT TO:<myemail@mydomain.com>
<<< 450 4.7.1 <localhost.localdomain>: Helo command rejected: Service temporarily unavailable
```

You can make Net::SMTP use another hostname in `HELO`/`EHLO` command by passing `Hello` parameter to `new`.

```
$smtp = Net::SMTP->new('smtpserver.mydomain.com', Hello => 'host.example.net');
```